# Sample Solidity Projects for learning?

Tags: solidity

Pardon me if this is not the right place.

I am looking for some example/use-case to learn and write first Solidity Smart Contract. Can you recommend some list which I can refer or you tell some interesting one?

I have given myself 2 weeks to finish it up.

Comment: Try CryptoZombies

Answer (score 5):

I can recommend this tutorial, it is really easy to follow and yet is formal. This helped me a lot some time ago.

[Dapps for beginners](https://dappsforbeginners.wordpress.com/tutorials/introduction-to-development-on-ethereum/)

Hope this helps

Comment: I think the question was more about smart contracts, your link has also all the stuff around it such as environments and web3 integration

Comment: Yes, it has many of the things you will need in order to (quote the OP) "to learn and write first Solidity Smart Contract.". I don't think to disregard the answer because it has more than what is asked is fair, even more, when the extra stuff is also about developing dapps.

Comment: I didn't say the answer should be disregarded, just commented that the answer is a bit more than what was asked for :) It's a totally vaild answer.

Answer (score 4):

The Truffle team has a nice demo that includes writing some Solidity in their [Pet Shop tutorial](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop).

Answer (score 3):

I like the Solidity [CryptoZombies](https://cryptozombies.io/) course for basic learning. To get set up with Truffle, which is very useful for deploying websites based around the blockchain use their [Pet Shop tutorial](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop).

But in terms of a good beginner project, think about these:

- Some form of gambling game. Doing this will help you learn about algorithms for randomness in Ethereum.
- Actual contracts, for example a wallet contract (multisignature), an escrow contract, a contract where someone arbitrates for a dispute

For more difficult, challenging projects, check these out:

- Some form of game like Cryptokitties.

For the hardest projects (not for a beginner for sure):

- A game where players can fight in turn-based strategy battles (think hearthstone)
- A clone of Steemit
- A decentralized exchange

Answer (score 0):

You can start your first dapp using a demo voter application and below is a link to all step-by-step development (and video) on the Ethereum blockchain using solidity.

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCY0xL8V6NzzFcwzHCgB8orQ

http://www.dappuniversity.com/articles/the-ultimate-ethereum-dapp-tutorial#dependencies

In 2022 you can use this link which is an excellent course

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyMwXuJrbJQ

Answer (score 0):

This is a project under work but i think this can be very right place to start: https://github.com/Aniket-Engg/solidity-school

Answer (score 0):

I think this tutorial is very good for beginners.
https://www.trufflesuite.com/tutorial